# How do I sort each string within a stream of strings?

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I am attempting to apply the map() function to a stream of strings right now such that the new stream contains a sorted version of each string.  That is, instead of "cat" it will have "act".  I am attempting to run the method as so:

```
Stream<String> sortedStream = validWordStream.map(s -> Arrays.sort(s.toString().toCharArray()));
```

However, it complains that the stream returned is a stream of Objects, not Strings:
[image]

## Question

What intuitive changes do I have to make to the map() function such that I get a stream of sorted strings?

Comment: You'll need to turn your sorted array of characters back into a String.

Comment: `Arrays.sort` method does not return anything, it is not a function, it sorts array in place. You cannot use it  like this with streams. You can do something like `s -> { char[] array = s.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(array); return new String(array); }`

Comment: By the way, the `char`  type has been legacy since Java 2. As a 16-bit value, it is physically incapable of representing most characters. Learn to use code point integer numbers instead for working with individual characters.

Comment: @BasilBourque the API to process a `String` in terms of codepoints has been introduced in Java 5. But the idea to sort the characters of a string in this way works only for ASCII letters anyway. Otherwise, you have to consider grapheme clusters and also discuss whether the operation shall convert between `σ` and `ς` when it changes the position and such alike.

Answer (score 3):

since `Array.sort`'s return type is `void`, you can not use its value as `map` result.
Also, you won't have correct result if there are surrogate pairs.

So:

```java
Stream<String> validWord = foo();
Stream<String> validSortedWord = validWord
    .map(s -> s.codePoints().sorted().toArray())
    .map(sortedCodepoints -> new String(sortedCodePoints, 0, sortedCodePoints.length))
```

(Edit: changed 3rd arguments of String constructor, see Sree Kumar's comment)

Comment: Nice answer. There is a defect, guess you hadn't tested your code. Change `sortedCodePoints.length - 1` to `sortedCodePoints.length`. Also, there is a case difference between the passed parameter name `sortedCodepoints` and the referred one.

Answer (score 0):

Sort each char array and then generate a new String:

```
Stream<String> sortedStream = validWordStream
      .map(s -> { char[] c = s.toCharArray(); 
                  Arrays.sort(c);
                  return new String(c);});
```